# How to make mpv use the pulseaudio volume controls again?

Tags: linux, pulse-audio, mpv

Since some recent update (mpv 0.18.something), mpv has stopped using the pulseaudio volume and instead used a software volume control.

This has downsides such as additional processing, but most importantly, the volume is not saved across mpv restarts anymore, while pulseaudio saves and restores the volume last used for mpv.

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To fix this, one can re-bind the volume control keys to use the `ao-volume` and `ao-mute` properties instead of the built-in softvol filter controls (see also [the corresponding ArchWiki entry](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/mpv#mpv_and_PulseAudio_since_0.18.1)).

For this we need to modify `~/.config/mpv/input.conf` (create it if it doesn’t exist) and add the following entries:

```
0 add ao-volume 2
9 add ao-volume -2 
m cycle ao-mute
```

This overrides the bindings existing for `0`, `9` and `m`. If you prefer to use the internal softvol additionally, use different keybindings as suggested in the linked ArchWiki entry.